# Pass widget input to DatabaseHelperSource file

Tags: java, android

Disclaimer: I am a newbie to Android development :)

How can I pass the string values collected from this first class to the class below? I attempted this but only got null values.

Here's my main activity.

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected SnapToSellDataSource mDataSource;

    public String sFullname;
    public String sEmail;
    public String sMobileNumber;
    public String sPassword;

    EditText full_name, email, mobile_number, pwd, copwd;
    Button registerButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mDataSource = new SnapToSellDataSource(Register.this);

        full_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        mobile_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        copwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Register register = new Register();

                String editPassword = pwd.getText().toString();
                String editConfirmPassword = copwd.getText().toString();

                    if(editPassword.equals(editConfirmPassword)) {

                    //This isn't overwriting the null class variables I 
                    //instantiated so that I can pass them to the class below

                    sFullname = full_name.getText().toString();
                    sEmail = email.getText().toString();
                    sMobileNumber = mobile_number.getText().toString();
                    sPassword = pwd.getText().toString();

                    mDataSource.insertUser(register);
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the class that should receive the string values:

```
public class SnapToSellDataSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private  SnapToSellHelper mHelper;
    private Context mContext;

    public SnapToSellDataSource(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mHelper = new SnapToSellHelper(mContext);
    }

    public void insertUser(Register register){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SnapToSellHelper.COL_NAME, register.sFullname);
        values.put(SnapToSellHelper.COL_EMAIL, register.sEmail);
        values.put(SnapToSellHelper.COL_NUMBER, register.sMobileNumber);
        values.put(SnapToSellHelper.COL_PASSWORD, register.sPassword);

        mDatabase.insert(SnapToSellHelper.TBL_USERS, null, values);
    }
}
```

I attempted to getText, getString from the second class but my app crashed maybe since the widgets were not yet assigned ids at the class level. Passing actual string values encased in quoation marks ("") works so it means the DatabaseHelper is properly set up.

I also tried declaring class variables and assigning the widget values to them but kept getting the "Cannot resolve symbol" error.

How you get a read from the local variables and pass them to the class variables that can then be set as public and read by another class; in this case, the second class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can not simply create instances** of an activity in Android. Activities are not classes that you just do a “**new**” on and call their constructor. An instance of an Activity is created when the app starts or when an Intent starts an activity.

So doing this: ***Register register = new Register();*** is not good! You can find good arguments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582309/why-cant-we-create-an-activity-using-new-keyword)

Instead you can pass those values as parameters to the *insertUser(params...)* method or create a new User class and instantiate it with those string values and pass it to ***insertUser(user)*** method.

*Method call:*

```
mDataSource.insertUser(sFullname, sEmail, sMobileNumber, sPassword);
```

*Method definition:*

```
public void insertUser(String sFullname, String sEmail, String sMobileNumber, String sPassword) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SnapToSellHelper.COL_NAME, sFullname);
    values.put(SnapToSellHelper.COL_EMAIL, sEmail);
    values.put(SnapToSellHelper.COL_NUMBER, sMobileNumber);
    values.put(SnapToSellHelper.COL_PASSWORD, sPassword);

    mDatabase.insert(SnapToSellHelper.TBL_USERS, null, values);
}
```

Comment: I have just attempted a User class below. What do you think of it. Let me see this edit you've just made as well.

Comment: Yes, this edit you added did the trick for me. So efficient and powerful. I was stuck. Thanks a lot!